# Habilitar y deshabilitar la conexión de datos del teléfono mediante código

Tags: android

Muy buenas, estoy desarrollando una aplicación para controlar el perfil de audio del teléfono y el de conexión (wifi y datos) y me encuentro en una encrucijada. Para habilitar o deshabilitar el wifi puedo usar el método WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(boolean enabled). Pero para hacer lo mismo con las redes móviles o datos no estoy encontrando la forma de hacerlo. ¿Alguien se ha tenido que pelear con ello o sabe como puedo habilitar y deshabilitar las redes moviles?

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba este código:

**java code**

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

**manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Respuesta original: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/24432035/5675636](http://Desactivar%20datos%20android) de Duggu.

Comment: Voy a probarlo muchas gracias!

Comment: me pasa lo mismo pero no logro aplicar del todo el codigo posteado anterior mente, podrias ayudarme. por favor